# Disk Manager for Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, diskmanagement, partition

I'm working with a Windows 2008 Server, and I'm currently trying to allocate unused space to the C Drive. I've run into a bit of an issue however as my disk partitions are in the following order:

C Drive | D Drive | Unused Space

From what I understand, the unused space needs to be immediately to the right of the partition for it to be allocated. Herein lies my problem!

So I was wondering if someone would be able to recommend a good disk manager that would allow me to do this? Something on the cheaper side if possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (avalible as a Live CD/USB) or part of Ubuntu can be used to "shuffle" partitions about. I have used this in the past when my OCD has got the better of me and I wanted to move the free space to the C drive. The process may take a while depending on space used.

As with any major disk paritioning, back up anything essential.